# Zopfli is written in C for portability... wait what?

Tags: c, compression, cross-platform

So I am not a C programmer so pardon this question.
I was reading this blog entry [Google Zopfli Compression](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.at/2013/02/compress-data-more-densely-with-zopfli.html?m=1) and I was a little dumbfounded by the following sentence : "Zopfli is written in C for portability".

How exactly is C a portable language? Or does he not mean portable in a compile-to-machine-code sense, but some other context? I guess C is more portable than writing assembly code. But is that really the comparison he is trying to make? I hope someone can enlighten me as to what he means and how exactly C is a portable language.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you hoping to use this library on some architecture that has no C compilers available?

Comment: Nope. This is just out of interest!

Comment: This is an unfortunate statement, you do not choose C *for* portability.

Comment: @ouah What exactly is the problem? How would you describe the relationship between choosing C and desiring portability?

Comment: Imho any language that runs on the JVM is more portable than C.

Comment: @delnan In the *spirit of C*, the C committee wrote about the language principles: *Make it fast, even if it is not guaranteed to be portable.*  You can achieve portability with C but choosing C for the reason of portability makes the assumption that C is more portable than some other modern languages which is wrong IMHO.

Comment: @ouah That's a interesting trivia, but (as also stated in the answers) the conclusion is wrong. Oh yes, you can do countless non-portable things in C (more than in higher-level languages). But a reasonable subset of it (core language + some libraries + some extensions) is not only defined such that it can work well on virtually any platform there is, as a matter of fact it **is** implemented on hundreds of platforms *right now*. That includes quite a few platforms that will never be supported by any other language, modern or not (e.g. embedded).

Comment: @MarcHPunkt the bytecode may well be distributable as-is with no extra work needed; but all you're doing is passing off the work to the people who have to port the JVM to your graphing calculator or your washing machine.

Comment: @MarcHPunkt It's theoretically perfectly portable in that *any* platform with a JVM can run it. However, in practice any platform with a JVM has a C compiler, and many with a C compiler don't have a JVM.

Comment: @delnan except that in JVM languages, nearly all the libraries will work cross-platform too. Which is not the case with C languages as far as I know

Comment: @MarcHPunkt True. But that's not always a concern, especially when you yourself implement a library that needs few or none dependencies -- which I assume is true in this case. A compression library doesn't need much.

Comment: @MarcHPunkt: The C standard libraries are cross-platform as well; the problem is that C does not provide standard libraries for a lot of "interesting" applications - networking, graphics, sound, file system management, etc., so for those applications you need to use third-party or system-specific libraries. However, you can structure your code such that the truly platform-dependent bits can be easily swapped out, leaving the bulk of the logic intact.

Comment: Which language that compiles to native code is more portable than C

Comment: Choosing Java over C for portability? <cry> Other way around, my friend. e.g.: [forum post](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/766474-java-on-openbsd/) notes about Java on one particular platform, "Executive summary: It can be done, it's just a pain in the rear to get it up and running." C supports tons of platforms. (Impressive since each is conceptual, and weightless.) e.g., with this sample (OpenBSD) C is an optional component in the OS's typical installation process. Java programs supports one platform, which require machines to have an interpreter installed. I like C's great portability

Answer (score 5):

Portable in this context means something like "Anybody can take this source code and compile it on their own computer and have this program."  Very nearly all computers drawing power somewhere today have a C compiler available for them (it may not be installed on that machine, but it's either available to be installed or is available as a cross-compiler (eg embedded systems)), so that same source code is portable virtually everywhere.  (EDIT: I'm assuming based on context that the source code doesn't have system-specific things in it, as system-specific things would limit your portability.)

Answer (score 5):

"Portability" has multiple meanings, depending on the context:

- The C *language* is "portable" in the sense that C compilers have been written for a wide variety of platforms, from mainframes to microcontrollers;
- The language is also "portable" in the sense that there is an agreed-upon standard that implementations conform to (to greater or lesser degree), so you don't have subtly different versions of the language depending on the vendor - the behavior of a conforming program should be the same on any conforming implementation;
- C *programs* that don't make any assumptions about the system they're running on (type sizes, alignment, endianess) or use system-specific libraries are often "trivially" portable; they only need to be recompiled for the target platform, without needing to edit the source code.

Compared to the majority of its contemporaries (Pascal, Fortran, etc.), C is *highly* portable, and I spent the bulk of the '90s writing C code that had to run on multiple platforms concurrently (one project required the same code to run on Windows NT, Solaris, and Classic MacOS).

C's portability can be summed up as "write once<sup>1</sup>, build and run everywhere", where Java and C#'s portability can be summed up as "write and build once, run everywhere."

---

<sup>1. Subject to the caveats in the third bullet</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For a piece of software to be considered cross-platform, it must be able to function on more than one computer architecture or operating system.

Developing such program can be a time-consuming task because different operating systems have different application programming interfaces (API). 
For example, Linux uses a different API for application software than Windows does.

C is a language you can use in most of the API.

Answer (score 0):

C code can be directly called in C++, and easily used in C# and I believe Objective-C.  That and the wide availability of c compilers, it does make sense.

Of course, the argument can also be made that Java is more portable as far as running it directly on other machines. But Java can't be moved from language to language as easily.